# How do i test "it" methods with truffle?

Tags: truffle, unittesting

I have this contract:

```
contract('MetaCoin', (accounts) => {
  it('should put 10000 MetaCoin in the first account', async () => {
    const metaCoinInstance = await MetaCoin.deployed();
    const balance = await metaCoinInstance.getBalance.call(accounts[0]);
    assert.equal(balance.valueOf(), 10000, "10000 wasn't in the first account");
  });



  it("thing test", async () => {
    const thing = await Thing.deployed();
    const res = await thing.specialThing.call(2, { from: accounts[0] });
    assert.equal(res, 200, "10000 wasn't in the first account");

  });
```

I'd like to specifically test `thing test` -- how do I do that with truffle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
it("thing test", async () => {
```

To this:

```
it.only("thing test", async () => {
```